# Sandwich rule for Lie algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

On an infinite dimensional vector space an operator can be onto but not one-to-one (and vice versa). This arises the following question. Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be Lie algebras (infinite dimensional, over some number field) and let $T_1:L_1\mapsto L_2$ and $T_2:L_2\mapsto L_1$ be Lie algebra homomorphisms onto. Is it true that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are isomorphic? Does it help if I know that $\ker T_1$ and $\ker T_2$ are Abelian ideals? Thank you.

This is a replication of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820276/sandwich-rule-for-lie-algebras) question on Math SE which has got no answers.

Comment: It's easy to find examples, so I have replied on MathSE (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820276/) rather than here.

Comment: As @YCor points out, this variant of Schröder–Bernstein doesn't hold, but there are others that do.  If you're interested in the theme rather than this particular question, you may enjoy https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/theme-and-variations-schroeder-bernstein .